# DKIM setting for Telus?

Tags: gmail, dkim

Does anyone know what I need to add to create a DKIM record for my domain if my ISP is Telus? I tried contacting Telus tech. support but no one there seems to have any idea what DKIM is. Telus now uses GMail for email so I'm guessing the subdomain is google_domainkey and Record Type is TXT but what would the IP Address or Target Host be?